# Allow select special characters

Tags: php, emoticons, chatroom

Hi I am using the `htmlentities()` PHP function for a chat room to prevent HTML being echo'd out into the chat.

Basically I want to allow this '<3' which PHP will replace with the Heart emoticon but due to the '<' symbol, the `htmlentities()` function is thinking it is HTML so it just comes out as plain text on the site like this '<3' and not the heart emoticon.

How can I allow users to type '<3' and it come out as a heart?

Comment: You need to show some code for anyone to be able to debug it.

Comment: The `<` will be replaced by `&lt;`. You could simply replace `&lt;3` with a heart shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace("&lt;3","<3", $msg['message_text']);` to replace the '<3' with a heart